# Node.js and express.js how to read 'get' endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to pass simple data from my server to a javascript file called on another html page. I am testing sending a single string from the server, but am not sure how to receive it. Server below:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static("./assets"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //res.send('Hello World!')
  res.sendFile('./main.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

app.get('/get-test', async (_req, res) => {
    try {
        const test_string = "get-test request string";
        return res.send(test_string);
    } catch (e) { throw e; }
});
```

And in another javascript file I have the following:

```
async function testing() {
    const response = await fetch('/get-test');
    console.log(response);
}
testing();
```

The `console.log` gives me a whole object, and clicking through it I can't seem to find my `test_string` anywhere:

[image]

So I believe the `get` request worked, but how do I actually access the data inside that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `await response.text()` before `console.log`ing it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a newbie when it comes to using express. And as a quick follow-up, what if my get request send a whole json object?

Comment: Then you can call `await response.json()`. Also, this isn't anything specific to Express, it's just part of the browser Fetch API, so you will have to call one of those methods after any HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

So in this functio:

```
async function testing() {
    const response = await fetch('/get-test');
    console.log(response);
}
testing();
```

You will need to put `await`  inside the console.log

so like this:

```
async function testing() {
    const response = await fetch('/get-test');
    console.log(await response);
}
testing();
```

## Why ?

Since javascript is asynchronous when retrieving data there will be a delay. That is why they implemented async / await and promises. So when you trying to make a get request with fetch you will need need to await the response. But the response is also a promise, which mean you will need to await the response aswell. This makes more sense, when you try to process the response to lets say json.

## A little tip

When the console.log returns no error, but no data either. It might because of a promise issue